# SQL trigger insert new variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to populate a column based on a certain condition when the table is updated with new rows using trigger.

Here is what I wrote.

```
create trigger [myschema].[charD] 
on [myschema].[deposits]
after update
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    update myschema.deposits
        set dayC = (convert(varchar, day, 23))
    from myschema.deposits
    where dayC is null
end
GO
```

This doesn't update or populate the column dayC when new rows are added, what am I missing here?

Comment: Because you have `after update` instead of `after insert`. Also you should **never** use `varchar` without specifying the length e.g. `varchar(64)` (but use whatever value is suitable for your application).

Comment: thank you Dale, i will try your suggestions

Comment: What happened to the `inserted` table, do you not use it? Bear in mind that triggers fire once *per statement* not once per row, and therefore `inserted` can have multiple rows

Comment: I pupdated the code this way `create trigger [myschema].[charD] 
on [myschema].[deposits]
after insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    update myschema.deposits
        set dayC = (convert(varchar, a.day, 23))
    from myschema.deposits a left join inserted i on a.id=i.id and a.test=i.test and a.day=i.day
    where i.dayC is null
end
go
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set dayC = (convert(varchar, day, 23))`

Looks like you are converting / formatting a `date` or `datetime` to string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Instead of using trigger, you can use a computed column

```
ALTER TABLE [myschema].[deposits]
    ADD [dayc] AS CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [day], 23)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to `after insert`

Also you have no correlation to the `inserted` table.

You need to join with `inserted` on your PK to update the inserted rows, otherwise you are updating all rows in your table every time.

[use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yeah, but it is OK to update a null column, knowing only the new values will be null.

Comment: Sure, but the same will result by joining to `inserted` and who knows, what happens when someone wants values on older rows to be reset to NULL for whatever reason and can't work out why their update mysteriously doesn't work...

Comment: You gotta know your business case, conversely you might want to ensure that all null values are always updated, even if someone sneakily set one to null. Its not the cause of the problem in this case, its just a recommendation.

Comment: As long as you know what's going on then of course; And even then, if there's no usable index or someone changes an existing index, performance could gradually degrade over time due to a table scan - seen that before lol. As you say it depends.